# How to rename a wireless connection and auto-connect to it?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, connection

How do I rename for example X 2 with X ?

I checked the SSID and it's not X 2.... I don't know how it got renamed to X 2

[image]

And how can I get it to auto-connect? When I click on it I don't get the nice "connect automatically" checkbox like on other connections :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the Control Panel>Network and Internet>Network and Sharing Center>Manage Wireless Networks

Click on the one you want, hit F2 and rename it.

To answer the second part, right-click on the connection, and hit properties. You can set it to automatically connect there by checking the top box, "Connect automatically when this network is in range".

Comment: thanks that worked. I see there that the it's set to "connect automatically" but whenever I start the PC it tries to connect to other networks...

Comment: Right-click on it, and move it up to give it a higher priority. And maybe uncheck the connect automatically for any other networks in your list you don't want to use, or remove them if they were added inadvertently (like a neighbor's wi-fi).